# How to query Reverse related field in the django serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I want a query result that looks like this in Django using a Serializer relations:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Article 1",
    "authors": ["John Doe", "Rose Mary"], 
  }
]
```

What I tried is  a slugRelatedField that looks like this:

```
authors = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="file__folder__workspace", many=True, read_only=True)
```

But it failed.
My model `Post` have `file` field and has a relation of  "file__folder__workspace". I want to fetch the authors that belong to the workspace.

Edit:
Model look like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
  username = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
  ...
class Workspace(models.Model):
  ...

class Folder(models.Model):
  workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class File(models.Model):
  folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Member(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace, related_name="members", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Post(models.Model):
  file = models.ForeignKey(File, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can you share your models too?

Comment: I update it @arjun